# Sending results of a SELECT to stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes one parameter. Ordinarily, it will be called as needed on a single id. Sometimes, though, it would be helpful to run it on every result from a SELECT. How can I take the results of a SELECT statement and run the stored procedure on each result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't directly possible, but...

As long as the stored procedure doesn't return a result-set, you can write a stored *function* that accepts the desired input and calls the procedure with the same value as an argument.  If a stored function is used in a select query, it will generally be called for each row returned, unless it's referenced in the where clause, in which case, the optimizer may call it for more rows than you might expect, depending on the query plan.

Or you can move the logic into a stored function directly instead of using a procedure at all.

Comment: Oh so close. I'll flag this as the answer, but this doesn't quite work. I need to modify data in the table that's being used for the SELECT, and MySQL doesn't like that - won't let me use a function to modify a table that's providing the data to the function.

Comment: Thanks, but all may not be lost.  There is a way to modify rows the same table you're selecting from, by materializing the rows into an anonymous temporary table.  Instead of `SELECT t1.foo, your_func(t1.bar) FROM table_name t1 WHERE ...` try something like `SELECT t1.foo, your_func(t1.bar) FROM (SELECT foo, bar FROM table_name WHERE ...) t1` ... this creates a temp table with the inner select's rows, so now, magically, `t1` is no longer an alias for the base table, it's an alias for the anonymous temporary table that's, conveniently, automatically, destroyed as soon as the query finishes.